# jsfidle filter not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the jsfiddle, i can get it to work with true, false values, but when i try to filter by name, it doesn't work any suggestions ?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtAZM/41/)

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <button class="btn" ng-click='filterCriteria={}'>All</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-click='filterCriteria.read=true'>Read</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-click='filterCriteria.title={{messages[0].title}}'>Foo</button>
    <pre>{{messages[0].title}}</pre>

    <hr/>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
              <td><strong>Content</strong></td>    
              <td><strong>Read</strong></td>    
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat='message in messages |filter:filterCriteria'>
              <td>{{message.title}}</td>
              <td>{{message.content}}</td>    
              <td>{{message.read}}</td>    
          </tr>
      </tbody>            
  </table>
</div>


    function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.filterCriteria = {};

    $scope.messages = [{
        title: 'Foo',
        content: 'Foo content',
        read: false},
    {
        title: 'Bar',
        content: 'Bar content',
        read: true}
            ];
     }
```

Comment: for example `$scope.filterCriteria = { title : 'Foo' };` - displays only foo row, what's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to use {{}} in ng-click

use ()

try

```
<button class="btn" ng-click='filterCriteria.title=(messages[0].title)'>Foo</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JtAZM/43/

Answer (score 3):

Since your filterCriteria is not cleared you are facing the issue.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtAZM/45/)

Try the below for filtering by name:

```
 $scope.filterByName= function(name){
    $scope.filterCriteria={},
    $scope.filterCriteria.title=name;
}
```

NOTE: I assume you are asking about new filtering when button is clicked and old filters are to be removed.

Comment: That's way better than my answer!

Comment: This a great answer,all logic should be moved to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the brackets:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click='filterCriteria.title=messages[0].title'>Foo</button>
```

Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mvcFW/)

Comment: Basically the same answer @UberChris gave.